# Sequelize require

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to use sequelize for the first time and I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

The console indicates that the error appears at this paragraph:

```
    var Sequelize  = require("sequelize")
  , sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'myusrname', 'mypass', {
      dialect: "mysql",
      port:    3306 
    });
```

What should I do?

Comment: `require` is a node.js construct, not sequelize. Can you require other modules?

Comment: You aren't mistakenly trying to run this code on the client?

Comment: As mentioned require is not part of JavaScript language definition but only nodejs implementation

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize(database, user, password,{
  dialect: 'mysql',
  port: 3306,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend a configuration like:

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'pass', {
      dialect: "mysql",
      port:    3306 
    });
const development = true;

// add some models:
const User = require('./models/user')(Sequelize, sequelize);
const File = require('./models/file')(Sequelize, sequelize);

// example of associated models:
User.hasMany(File);
File.belongsTo(User);

// development? update db structure
if (development) sequelize.sync();

// Create a map of your db models 
const dbMap = { "Sequelize": Sequelize,
             "sequelize": sequelize,
             "models": { 
                        "User": User,
                        "File": File
                      }
            };

module.exports = dbMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

Mainatain config file with database details and use it as below

```
var config = require('./config/config');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database,config.username,config.password,{
  host:config.db.host,
  dialect:config.db.dialect,
  pool:{
    min:config.min,
    max:config.max,
    idle:config.idle
  }
});

 sequelize.authenticate().then(function (err) {
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
});
```